# Getting an error while installing memcache on xampp (Windows 7)

Tags: php, windows-7, memcached

I followed below steps to install memcache in xampp.But I am getting below error

```
    1.start xampp.
    2.click on 'config' and open php.ini file.

    I didn't found this line ;extension=php_memcache.dll in php.ini.
    So i added following lines
    extension=php_memcache.dll
    [Memcache]
    memcache.allow_failover = 1
    memcache.max_failover_attempts=20
    memcache.chunk_size =8192
    memcache.default_port = 11211 

   3. Then i downloaded the php_memcache.dll file and pasted in the  localtion D:\xampp\php\ext.

   4. Downloaded Memcache server for windows and pasted the Memcache.exe in c:/memcached/memcached.exe 

   5. Open the cmd prompt with “Run as Administrator” and execute the line to install c:/memcached/memcached.exe -d install when i press enter iam getting the following error
```

Error:

> The program can’t start because MSVCR71.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this program.